# Javascript regex to replace special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

How to replace these symbols "ąčęėįšųūž" with these symbols "aceeisuuz" in javascript? I know I need to use regex, but I can't make pattern.

this is what I have

```
var string = $(this).val();
        string = string.replace(/\s+/g, '-').toLowerCase();
        string = string.replace(/[^a-zA-Z0-9-]/g,'_');
        string = regExp something here...

    $("#custom_url").val(string);
```

**UPDATE:**

found this solution in other thread:

```
function convert_accented_characters(str){
    var conversions = new Object();
    conversions['ae'] = 'ä|æ|ǽ';
    conversions['oe'] = 'ö|œ';
    conversions['ue'] = 'ü';
    conversions['Ae'] = 'Ä';
    conversions['Ue'] = 'Ü';
    conversions['Oe'] = 'Ö';
    conversions['A'] = 'À|Á|Â|Ã|Ä|Å|Ǻ|Ā|Ă|Ą|Ǎ';
    conversions['a'] = 'à|á|â|ã|å|ǻ|ā|ă|ą|ǎ|ª';
    conversions['C'] = 'Ç|Ć|Ĉ|Ċ|Č';
    conversions['c'] = 'ç|ć|ĉ|ċ|č';
    conversions['D'] = 'Ð|Ď|Đ';
    conversions['d'] = 'ð|ď|đ';
    conversions['E'] = 'È|É|Ê|Ë|Ē|Ĕ|Ė|Ę|Ě';
    conversions['e'] = 'è|é|ê|ë|ē|ĕ|ė|ę|ě';
    conversions['G'] = 'Ĝ|Ğ|Ġ|Ģ';
    conversions['g'] = 'ĝ|ğ|ġ|ģ';
    conversions['H'] = 'Ĥ|Ħ';
    conversions['h'] = 'ĥ|ħ';
    conversions['I'] = 'Ì|Í|Î|Ï|Ĩ|Ī|Ĭ|Ǐ|Į|İ';
    conversions['i'] = 'ì|í|î|ï|ĩ|ī|ĭ|ǐ|į|ı';
    conversions['J'] = 'Ĵ';
    conversions['j'] = 'ĵ';
    conversions['K'] = 'Ķ';
    conversions['k'] = 'ķ';
    conversions['L'] = 'Ĺ|Ļ|Ľ|Ŀ|Ł';
    conversions['l'] = 'ĺ|ļ|ľ|ŀ|ł';
    conversions['N'] = 'Ñ|Ń|Ņ|Ň';
    conversions['n'] = 'ñ|ń|ņ|ň|ŉ';
    conversions['O'] = 'Ò|Ó|Ô|Õ|Ō|Ŏ|Ǒ|Ő|Ơ|Ø|Ǿ';
    conversions['o'] = 'ò|ó|ô|õ|ō|ŏ|ǒ|ő|ơ|ø|ǿ|º';
    conversions['R'] = 'Ŕ|Ŗ|Ř';
    conversions['r'] = 'ŕ|ŗ|ř';
    conversions['S'] = 'Ś|Ŝ|Ş|Š';
    conversions['s'] = 'ś|ŝ|ş|š|ſ';
    conversions['T'] = 'Ţ|Ť|Ŧ';
    conversions['t'] = 'ţ|ť|ŧ';
    conversions['U'] = 'Ù|Ú|Û|Ũ|Ū|Ŭ|Ů|Ű|Ų|Ư|Ǔ|Ǖ|Ǘ|Ǚ|Ǜ';
    conversions['u'] = 'ù|ú|û|ũ|ū|ŭ|ů|ű|ų|ư|ǔ|ǖ|ǘ|ǚ|ǜ';
    conversions['Y'] = 'Ý|Ÿ|Ŷ';
    conversions['y'] = 'ý|ÿ|ŷ';
    conversions['W'] = 'Ŵ';
    conversions['w'] = 'ŵ';
    conversions['Z'] = 'Ź|Ż|Ž';
    conversions['z'] = 'ź|ż|ž';
    conversions['AE'] = 'Æ|Ǽ';
    conversions['ss'] = 'ß';
    conversions['IJ'] = 'Ĳ';
    conversions['ij'] = 'ĳ';
    conversions['OE'] = 'Œ';
    conversions['f'] = 'ƒ';

    for(var i in conversions){
        var re = new RegExp(conversions[i],"g");
        str = str.replace(re,i);
    }

    return str;
}
```

Comment: @ŽydriusNežydras, You should answer your your own question as an actual "answer" rather than an "update" in your question. That way the answer is helpful to others in the future.  It is perfectly fine to answer your own question.  :)